# Python create a sublist of list from a list

Tags: python

Here is my question: I have a list in python that looks like this:

```
list = [["a", "b", [1,2]], ["a", "C", [4,1,3]], ["e", "f", [1,7]]]
```

And I would like to get a sublist like this:

```
sublist = [[1,2], [4,1,3], [1,7]]
```

I would like to know if there is a quick way to make this transition,

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `list` as a name for a list as it clashes with the built-in name. Use this:

```
l = [["a", "b", [1,2]], ["a", "C", [4,1,3]], ["e", "f", [1,7]]]
sublist = [i[-1] for i in l]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [1, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m = [i[2] for i in list]
print(m)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [1, 7]]
```